# Build issue with eclipse web app

Tags: class, tomcat, web, build

I have a web app created in eclipse. After some strange changes I made, which I can't remember, all classes under the build directory do not work. Specifically when I open them I get these stuff:

Class File Editor

Source not found

There is no source attached to the class file foo.class

// Compiled from foo.java (version 1.7 : 51.0, super bit)
public class Beans.foo implements java.io.Serializable {

// Field descriptor #8 J
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

................
................
................
................

Although, the classes under the WebContent directory work fine.

(also tomcat can't start, and i think it is because of this)

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I copied and pasted all the java files from WebContent into build, but now eclipse understands the same java files (that exist also in build and in webContent) as different files.
thank you.

Comment: You're trying to open .class files in Eclipse. Why? Open the source files (.java) instead.

Comment: No I meant the .java files. When I open them (the ones which are under the build directory) I get the above message. Maybe I removed them from the build path, I don't know exactly what I did there. But how can I fix this?

Comment: Your question is a little bit messy. You have the .java classes in the source dir, correct? You cannot run the app? Or you just want to open the .class and see the source?